# Enter Image URL (http://...) in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, url

I tried using this in mysql:

```
      INSERT INTO users (url) VALUES (http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljtc6i9GPA1qbq4v6o1_400.gif) WHERE id='15';
```

But it gives this error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljtc6i9GPA1qbq4v6o1_400.gif) WHERE id='15'' at line 1"
```

Can anyone tell me what is the reason and how to store the url in the table?

Comment: `INSERT` query with `WHERE` condition.. what reason??

Comment: use quotes: `'http://...'`

Comment: make single quotes around your char values and removed it at decimal values. But what are you triing to do? You mix the insert und update syntax!

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my bad. I was using update and insert together and mixed them up. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO statements don't have a WHERE clause. If you are wanting to use a WHERE clause you are just UPDATEing a row.
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;